# Does Webpack code splitting provide a polyfill for dynamic import for older browsers?

Tags: javascript, webpack, code-splitting, dynamic-import

I've been trying to find out more information on Webpack's code splitting feature, using the `import()` function, which is still in Stage 3 of the TC39 and only supported by Chrome and Safari, at the time of writing this. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36746594/1549703) indicates that it is polyfilled with script tag injection, but I can't find any other references for this, and Webpack's source code confounds me with all its plugins etc. Before converting my codebase to use `import()` and going through a lot of trouble potentially for nothing, I'd like to know what the browser support is for Webpack's code splitting. The docs just say it depends on `Promise`, which is acceptable for me, but are there any other potential limitations to be aware of? How does this feature work under the hood?

Comment: I think it only needs `Promise`, not even `fetch()`: https://github.com/webpack/webpack#browser-compatibility

Comment: Oh yes, you're right! Thx!